# Gradient Descent: AssertionError: shapes of matrix don't match

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I am stuck on assignment from Andrew Ng DL-NN course. 
The code has a assertion when matrix gradient of the loss with respect to `w` ( `dw` ) must have the same shape of `w` ( `.shape == ( 2, 1 )` ) but in calculating `dw` I have to include the matrix of variable `X`, that has a shape of `(2,2)`, so by broadcasting the shape of `dw` will always be `(2,2)` and never the same as `w` `(2,1)`.

Can someone help please?

Function

```
def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    """
    Implement the cost function and its gradient for the propagation explained above
    Arguments:
    w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
    b -- bias, a scalar
    X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat) of size (1, number of examples)
    Return:
    cost -- negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression
    dw -- gradient of the loss with respect to w, thus same shape as w
    db -- gradient of the loss with respect to b, thus same shape as b    
    """
    m = X.shape[1] 

    A = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(np.dot(w.T, X) + b)))                           
    cost = -(1/m) *(np.dot(Y, np.log(A).T)) + (1 - Y) * np.log(1-A)             
    dz = A - Y
    dw = (1/m)*X*((dz.T))
    db = (1/m)*np.sum(dz)

    #print(X.shape)
    #print(X)
    #print(A.shape)
    #print(Y.shape)
    print(dw.shape)
    #print(dw)
    #print(w.shape)

    assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
    assert(db.dtype == float)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert(cost.shape == ())

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}
    return grads, cost
```

Call Function

```
w, b, X, Y = np.array([[1],[2]]), 2, np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), 
np.array([[1,0]])
grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
print ("dw = " + str(grads["dw"]))
print ("db = " + str(grads["db"]))
print ("cost = " + str(cost))
```

Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-93098709c7a5> in <module>()
      1 w, b, X, Y = np.array([[1],[2]]), 2, np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), np.array([[1,0]])
----> 2 grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
      3 print ("dw = " + str(grads["dw"]))
      4 print ("db = " + str(grads["db"]))
      5 print ("cost = " + str(cost))

<ipython-input-82-e28b1a4b33cb> in propagate(w, b, X, Y)
     45     ### END CODE HERE ###
     46 
---> 47     assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
     48     assert(db.dtype == float)
     49     cost = np.squeeze(cost)

AssertionError:
```

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: @DYZ  already include the message error

Answer (score 0):

First of all cost is wrong, it should be something among the lines of:

```
cost = -(1./m) * np.sum(Y * np.log(A) + (1 - Y) * np.log(1-A)  )
```

second, "*" is not matrix multiply but rather a pointwise one, so dw should be

```
dw = (1/m)*X.dot(dz.T)
```

I am not checking math correctness here, just shapes of your objects.